# What is best watering schedule for a bonsai juniper tree?

Tags: watering, bonsai

I am new to bonsai and I have had two juniper bonsai trees so far. The first one dried out even though I watered it weekly. The second one I am keeping pretty well moist but I am afraid of drowning it.

What is best schedule for watering my juniper bonsai and are there any good resources I should look at as a newbie?  Here is a photo of how it looks today. I keep in indoors.

[image: my bonsai]

Answer (score 4):

What b0n2a1 said. It's drying out because houses are too dry for junipers usually.  They can be kept indoors if done very carefully and humidity is maintained. Generally you winter junipers outside for the winter.  That's where all mine are this winter.

Answer (score 1):

This tree appears to be a juniperus procubens nana. Junipers are hardy outdoor plants and typically will not survive long in the house. They like free draining soil. With a very free draining soil in full summer sun you will need to water daily. In the winter you may only need to water once a week. I live in the pacific north west so I rarely have to water my junipers in the winter. 
Some good bonsai links are:[Crataegus.com](http://crataegus.com/tag/juniper-bonsai/), [BonsaiTonight.com](http://bonsaitonight.com/)
If there is a bonsai club in your area that will be your best resource for local information.

Comment: 'Junipers are hardy outdoor plants and typically will not survive long in the house' - I think that's not correct. I knew someone who kept one in his house as a houseplant till it got too big, but put it in a cold room overwinter